# If I use Streamlit's `st.cache_data` to cache a DataFrame, is that available to all users to the deployed app?

Tags: streamlit

On my deployed app, I have `st.cache_data()` decorating a function to load a DataFrame `df`. When User 1 loads up my app for the first time, data loading function takes while but subsequent interactions by User 1 will not trigger the data loading function again because the `df` is cached.

I'd like to understand what happens when User 2 loads up the app. Does user 2 observe the same experience as User 1? Or because User 1's df is still cached, does User 2 get to use the cached `df` directly?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate 2 users ? For example by opening a new private browsing session and accessing your app (this way you don't share history, cookies, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streamlit's caching functions cache across all sessions/users. If you would like to save a value across just one session, I'd recommend using [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) instead.